# Use of undefined constant notice

Tags: php, notice

I've read up on this problem a little, mainly from articles on here. It appears that it is typically generated by someone trying to do `$foo[bar]` instead of `$foo['bar']`, but I have checked several times around where the error is occuring in my script and this is *not* the case.

I have a php file, which contains the following script:

```
define("APP_PATH", "http://localhost/foobar");

require_once APP_PATH . "/classes/controller.php";
```

This appears to be executing fine. Inside `controller.php` I have this code:

```
require_once APP_PATH . "/classes/factory.class.php";

$factory = new factory;
```

This, to my knowledge, should execute perfectly fine. However, I am getting the following error: `Notice: Use of undefined constant APP_PATH - assumed 'APP_PATH' in C:\wamp\www\foobar\classes\controller.php on line 3`. Line 3 is the call to `require_once`.

I have checked, I am fairly sure that this should not be causing an error. I've also checked my spelling. The same line also triggers a warning and a fatal error about failing to open the stream, it is returning `APP_PATH/classes/factory.class.php` as the path.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i feel this has to do something with the fact your using a URI scheme to include the file

Comment: Because if you include a file as a URL, you're going to get the processed file. PHP tries to process controller.php in order to send it to the requesting file, but the constant hasn't been defined there. I hope that made sense :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, changing the definition away from a http:// based URL worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including from a remote place.

Let's say that `APP_PATH.'/classes/controller.php'` is as follows:

```
<?php
class Some_Controller extends Controller {
    // ...
}
echo 'TEST!';
```

When you include it through HTTP the PHP interpreter will parse the file before sending it back to be included:

```
<?php
include APP_PATH.'/classes/controller.php';
// This will print "TEST!" to the page because PHP has
// parsed the code and the only thing in the output
// buffer is "TEST!" (from the "echo 'TEST!';")
```

In order to fix this you need to include from the local environment. In Linux it would be some like

```
/path/to/web/classes/controller.php
```

In Windows it would be something like:

```
C:\path\to\web\classes\controller.php
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response. I changed the definition of APP_PATH to `dirname(__FILE__)`, which appears to be working.

Comment: If you have PHP >=5.3.0 then you can also set it to `__DIR__`.